# ASUS P6X58D and 12 GB of RAM

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, memory, motherboard

I just assembled my new PC and it screams, BUT it's only recognizing 8 GB of RAM in BIOS and OS rather than the installed 12 GB. In the BIOS the RAM was registering at 1066 MHz so I set it to 1600 MHz. I updated the BIOS to the latest non-beta release.

http://www.asus.com/product.aspx?P_ID=wurRaDZ8lo4Ckukj

- OS: Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit
- Motherboard: ASUS P6X58D Premium
- CPU: Intel Core i7 920
- RAM: CORSAIR XMS3 12 GB (6 x 2 GB) 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 1600
- HDD: Intel 80 GB SSD SATA II
- Power supply: Kingwin 1000 W Modular

I've installed the Beta BIOS 0808 but no luck!

Answer (score 0):

Drop RAM speed to 1333 MHz, most memory controllers on the CPU won't be able to run all 12 GB at 1600 MHz.

Comment: I've been tinkering with this for a while and it seems like the 3rd channel is just dead. No RAM registers. I have a new mobo en route.